# Allow only numeric characters VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have been working in an excel data table, and need to automate the removal of letters in a column.

This is what I've tried:

```
Sub SacaLetras()

    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    RE.Global = True
    RE.Pattern = [a-z]
    For Each RE In Worksheets("Candidatos").Range("P")
    Cells.Replace(RE,"0")
    Next RE
End Sub
```

Thank you all!

Comment: What is it doing that is in error?

Comment: Syntax error it says

Comment: on what line is the error?

Comment: I see that the error might be the "replace" command.  Line 11. But it also marks the Sub declaration in yellow.
What I was trying to do is to make the program find any non-numeric characters located in column P.
Tks !

Comment: I think you might need to put quotes around your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

The pattern needs to be a string, put it in quotes.

Do not iterate the whole column.

When you iterate you need to put it in a range object not the regex object.

You need to tell vba where to put the new value.  I am overwriting the cell itself:

```
Sub SacaLetras()

    Dim RE As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    RE.Global = True
    RE.Pattern = "[a-z]"
    For Each cell In Intersect(Worksheets("Candidatos").Range("P:P"), Worksheets("Candidatos").UsedRange)
        cell.Value = RE.Replace(cell.Value, "0")
    Next cell
End Sub
```